# How to format zsh completion "interactive" menu?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

It is usually relatively straightforward to format zsh completion system results e.g.,

`zstyle ':completion:*:warnings' format ' %F{red}-- no matches found --%f'`

When using the interactive menu mode (e.g., `zstyle ':completion:*' menu select interactive`), an extra line is added to the terminal menu

```
> cd searchstring
interactive: searchstring[] <-- this one!
--- the results
```

Is it possible to format the `interactive: searchstring[]` line? I have tried modifying the above `zstyle format` command with all the standard tags I can think of, but none seem to work.

Is this possible?